# Google sheets. Summing values with different filters

Tags: google-sheets

I've recently started studying google sheets and I have a problem.
The table is kind of like warehouse accounting. I have a range of values with completed operations. I want to calculate balances by product name. If I count just the amount, I have everything counting correctly. But I want to make filters so that I can understand how many items for example on a certain project or in what department. Or all three criteria at once.
In the first screenshot, the final value, taking into account income and expenses only by name of the item. On the second screen when selecting the filter. In the first case, the value is correct. In other cases, it is not.
Below is a link to my file for calculating.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LqddbhVrm-hIZe66j1y7_Wz4WJNCpPX5yWT1-tJKIm8/edit?usp=sharing

Also, there are pictures

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have tried several variants with the formula IF, ISBLANK. At the moment there is no result

Maybe there are other ways to calculate? Or use google apps script?

Answer (score 0):

Use `QUERY()` function instead.

```
=QUERY(A:F;"select sum(B) where A like '%" & H1 & "%' and C like '%"&I2&"%' and D like '%" & J2 & "%' and E like '%" & K2 & "%' label sum(B) ''";0)
```

Same formula for cleaner looking

```
=QUERY(A:F;
"select sum(B) 
where A like '%" & H1 & 
"%' and C like '%" & I2 & 
"%' and D like '%" & J2 & 
"%' and E like '%" & K2 & 
"%' label sum(B) ''";0)
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, thank you. Now there is a calculation of the total amount. How do I make it so that only leftovers are counted? By leftovers I mean "Income - Expenses - Sells".

Comment: Use `Group by` clause.

Comment: @DmSt Try `=QUERY(A:F;"select F, sum(B) where A like '%" & H1 & "%' and C like '%" & I2 & "%' and D like '%" & J2 & "%' and E like '%" & K2 & "%' group by F label sum(B) ''";0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach using [*DSUM*](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094281)

```
=dsum({A:A\{B1;index(if(len(F2:F);if(F2:F="Income";1;-1)*B2:B;))}\C:F};2;H1:K2)
```

- Make sure the criteria table in `H1:K2` is formatted exact as shown in the screenshot with ***headers*** showcased in `H1:K1` and ***drop-downs*** in `H2:K2`
- `(Income) - (expense) - (sells)` calculation is also embedded

[image]